# My Visual Studio 2015 install now displays "..." for quick info everywhere

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Does anyone know what would cause visual studio to display a gray box containing "..." in place of quick info everywhere?  I cannot figure out what is causing IntelliSense to break in this fashion.  I have even tried uninstalling and re-installing visual studio 2015 to fix it, but with no success.  Whatever is causing this (whether registry entry or file) is being left behind by the uninstaller apparently.  It is incredibly frustrating not being able to see method or property descriptions.  I am using community edition on windows 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

First try running VS2015 in [SafeMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278.aspx)

If after running safe mode you are now able to view Quick Info and the "..." has gone away, then it is a 3rd-party software that is interfering with IntelliSense.

In my case, CodeRush was the interference, so I will answer to the solution I found for the 3rd-party CodeRush.

In Visual Studio, open the tab DevExpress > CodeRush > Options

In the option, open Editor > Training > IntelliRush

Uncheck the "Enabled" checkbox at the top and apply.